# JSON is not recognizing accents nor question marks in ios

Tags: ios, xcode, nsjsonserialization, json

I'been trying to parse JSON data retrieved from my server, but when the server sends JSON with accents or question marks, it shows as null values.

It would be great if someone could help me solve this issue.

Here is my code

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];

NSString *urls=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://myserver.myserver/myserver"];
NSLog(@"%@",urls);
NSURL *url =[NSURL URLWithString:urls];

NSData* data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
//fetch the data to the JSON Foundation opject.
[self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(fetchedData:)
                       withObject:data waitUntilDone:YES];
}
- (void)fetchedData:(NSData *)responseData {
//parse out the json data
NSError* error;
NSDictionary    *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData options:kNilOptions error:&error];
//process the JSON Foundation object to the view.
[self processData:json];

}
-(void)processData:(NSDictionary *) JSONObject{
NSString *kl = [JSONObject valueForKey:@"qlk"];
NSString *an= [JSONObject valueForKey:@"alk"];
NSString *bn = [JSONObject valueForKey:@"blk"];
NSString *cn =[JSONObject valueForKey:@"clk"];
NSString *dn =[JSONObject valueForKey:@"dlk"];
NSString *correcta =[JSONObject valueForKey:@"rlk"];

qkl.text=pregunta;
akl.text =an;
bkl.text =bn;
ckl.text=cn;
dkl.text=dn;
}
```

And the JSON

```
{ "qlk": "¿De qué color es el caballo blanco de Simon Bolivar?", "alk": "Negro", "blk": "Cafe", "clk": "Blanco", "dlk": "Rojo", "rlk": "c" }
```

Thanks.

Comment: It is difficult to help if you don't show the JSON data. Side note: `objectForKey:` is the designated method to retrieve a dictionary value, not `valueForKey:`.

Comment: Ok sorry I added it thanks

Comment: That should work without problems. Did you check if `json == nil`? What is the value of `error`? Are you sure that the server sends the JSON data UTF-8 encoded?